# Is it possible to to programmatically detect changes of IP address on a specific ethernet interface on windows XP?

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, c++-cli, windows-embedded

I can easily check IP addresses programmatically, but is there any way to set up a notification in case the IP address of an in interface changes?

This can be a windos API or .net solution; either is fine.

Comment: [NotifyAddrChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or one of the other Notify* functions should do the job.

Comment: @arx: This is a valid answer. Perhaps you have posted it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NotifyAddrChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366329%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or one of the other Notify* functions should do the job.

This is also supported on various embedded versions of Windows.